# i use the /say command and try to fix

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

main.py

```
import discord
from discord import app_commands
from discord.ext import commands
from commandall import say

bot = commands.Bot(intents = discord.Intents().all(),command_prefix='!')

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print("==================\n>>Bot is Online<<\n==================\n Log in acc is",bot.user)
    try:
        syned=await bot.tree.sync()
        print(f'syned {len(syned)} command(s)')
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)


@bot.tree.command(name='say', description='what i to say')
async def say(ctx, text: str):
    await say(ctx, text)

bot.run('w')
```

commandall/say.py

```
import discord
from discord import app_commands

async def say(ctx, text: str):
    await ctx.send(f'{text}')
    print(f'{ctx.guild.name} >> {ctx.author.name} > SAY > {text} (✅)')
```

[in the discord use /say](https://i.stack.imgur.com/00NJv.png)

and err

```
ERROR    discord.app_commands.tree Ignoring exception in command 'say'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\discord\app_commands\commands.py", line 828, in _do_call
    return await self._callback(interaction, **params)  # type: ignore
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\discord bot\discord-bot\main.py", line 28, in say
    await say(ctx, text)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: 'Command' object is not callable

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\discord\app_commands\tree.py", line 1248, in _call
    await command._invoke_with_namespace(interaction, namespace)
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\discord\app_commands\commands.py", line 853, in _invoke_with_namespace
    return await self._do_call(interaction, transformed_values)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\discord\app_commands\commands.py", line 842, in _do_call    
    raise CommandInvokeError(self, e) from e
discord.app_commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command 'say' raised an exception: TypeError: 'Command' object is not callable
```

i want to separate the command

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you use the same name `say` to define your function and your command. You can disambiguate this by importing the `commandall` module and using `commandall.say`:

```py
import discord
from discord import app_commands
from discord.ext import commands
import commandall

bot = commands.Bot(intents = discord.Intents().all(),command_prefix='!')

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print("==================\n>>Bot is Online<<\n==================\n Log in acc is",bot.user)
    try:
        syned=await bot.tree.sync()
        print(f'syned {len(syned)} command(s)')
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)


@bot.tree.command(name='say', description='what i to say')
async def say(ctx, text: str):
    await commandall.say(ctx, text)

bot.run('w')
```

Answer (score 0):

What @Hazzu said on the answer is correct, just need to correct a few things.

First off, I think you should change up the imports a bit off from what I've read on the question, so it should change to:

`from commandall import say` -> `from commandall.say import *`
This way you can do `await say(ctx, text)` just like you did on your original code. (The `*` is universal which means it will take any functions from the specified python file you imported.)

Second, about the say command, I think I should talk about this. As far as i'm aware (for slash commands at least), you do not need context (or `ctx`) as an argument anymore, you should use `discord.Interactions` instead ([This Gist Page](https://gist.github.com/AbstractUmbra/a9c188797ae194e592efe05fa129c57f) explains slash commands well, written from a very known discord.py community member.)

So It should be like this :

The `Main.py` file you did on your say command

```py
import discord
from discord import app_commands
from discord.ext import commands
from commandall.say import * # Changed the import

bot = commands.Bot(intents = discord.Intents().all(),command_prefix='!')

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print("==================\n>>Bot is Online<<\n==================\n Log in acc is",bot.user)
    try:
        syned=await bot.tree.sync()
        print(f'syned {len(syned)} command(s)')
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)


@bot.tree.command(name='say', description='What I am gonna to say')
async def say(interaction : discord.Interaction, text: str): # Changed ctx -> discord.Interaction
    await say(interaction, text)

bot.run('w')
```

And for the `Say.py` file

```py
import discord
# Removed "from discord import app_commands" as it isnt relevant to the code, y'know, to make it more cleaner

async def say(interaction, text: str):
    await interaction.response.send_message(f'{text}')
    print(f'{interaction.guild.name} >> {interaction.author.name} > SAY > {text} (✅)') # Changed the asynchronous function of the attribute "ctx" to "interaction"
```

Or even better, just save yourselves from headache and not separate the say functions for readable code (although you don't want but that's okay)

```
@bot.tree.command(name='say', description='What I am gonna to say')
async def say(interaction : discord.Interaction, text: str): # Changed ctx -> discord.Interaction
    await interaction.response.send_message(text)
    print(f'{interaction.guild.name} >> {interaction.author.name} > SAY > {text} (✅)')
```

That's all from me, lemme know if theres any mistakes I made